# ActionBarSherlock becoming transparent when using windowActionBarOverlay

Tags: android, styles, actionbarsherlock, transparent

I'm using ActionBarSherlock for an Android app I'm making, and am displaying an image on one of my screens. On this screen, I want the actionbar to go away and come back as the user presses on the screen without the image being stretched. This part I have working, but to do so I created the following style and applied it to that screen. . .

```
<style name="DarkActionBar.ActionBarOverlay" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

The problem is, now my action bar is transparent and I can't figure out why. If I change the parent of my style to Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, it is no longer transparent but doesn't look the same as Theme.Sherlock, so it will be inconsistent with the rest of my app.

I've also tried the following. . .

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/black</item>
    <item name="background">@color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="DarkActionBar.ActionBarOverlay" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
```

Can anyone tell me why the windowActionBarOverlay items are making my actionbar transparent, and what I can do to fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As the transparent ActionBar is a feature called "Actionbar Overlay", I think the problem is inside this line:

```
<item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```

You may need to set it to `false`.

Please have a read of the following paragraph:

> To enable overlay mode for the action bar, you need to create a custom
>   theme that extends an existing action bar theme and set the
>   android:windowActionBarOverlay property to true

Also please have a look at [Overlaying the Actionbar on Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html)